# паралельность исполнения ф-ций (Си): обновить вывод по таймеру ожидая ввода в ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

Итак, у меня есть программа, которая выводит на экран судоку и позволяет ее решать записывая туда символы; еще есть ф-ция таймер (самый простой), которая отсчитывает секунды от начала решения. Как сделать так, чтобы таймер отсчитывал время паралельно с выполнением основной программы? С момента запуска проги она ждет ввода (использована ф-ция getch(), ncurses), после этого обрабатывает его, выводит на экран результат и сново ждет ввода - я не знаю как сделать так, чтобы "таймер", будучи частью программы, отсчитывал секунды независимо от ввода. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не совсем понял как выводится время, но в Вашем случае можно при старте запоминать системное время, а в процессе вычислять разность от текущего, которая и будет временем выполнения.

Comment: можно не вызывать блокирующие функции, а с помощью select (или аналогов) ожидать ввода с клавиатуры и просыпаться периодически, чтобы экран обновить (таймер). [первый попавшийся из поисковика пример](http://keyvanfatehi.com/2011/08/02/Asynchronous-c-programs-an-event-loop-and-ncurses/)

Comment: По поводу вычисления времени - и как это будет работать? Время ведь будет показываться только после ввода - это уже не таймер.

Comment: вот пример на Питоне: [тикают часы, пока ввод от пользователя ожидается в терминале](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/examples/clock-input.py) (использует фоновый поток по умолчанию)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку Вы используете ncurses, то самый правильный и простой путь - воспользоваться возможностями этого пакета.

1. В главном окне программы создаём два дочерних окна: игровое поле и строку статуса;
2. Назначаем каждому из этих окон функцию обработки
3. Запускаем соответствующие функции как нити. (С помощью библиотеки pthread)

По поводу пункта 2 почитайте:

```
man 3 threads
```

Попытка запустить нити-обработчики окон без уведомления об этом библиотеки ncurses приведёт к непредсказуемым результатам.

Answer (score 0):

1. Почему бы не использовать системные таймеры? (раз ncurses, то видимо речь про unix?)
2. можно запустить другой поток и в нем отсчитывать время своим таймером.

Comment: Если я запущю другой поток, то ф-ция будет идти паралельно с основной прогой? Если да, то не подскажете как это сделать? Что же касается вида таймера - это совершенно неважно, какой там таймер, главное чтобы отсчитывал время пока выполняется основная прога.

Comment: У меня появилось подозрение, что Вы под словом "таймер" понимаете что-то свое. Вот пример использования таймера в unix: http://wm-help.net/lib/b/book/2075737573/339 Что же касается потоков - да, они для того и созданы, чтобы выполняться одновременно. И снова, на зная целевой платформы, я не могу давать примеры с потоками. Если речь про linux (или bsd), почитайте про POSIX threads - в их использовании нет ничего сложного.

Comment: А при чем сдесь unix, для начала? что касается таймера - то это обычный таймер, отсчитывающий время и выводящий его на экран - в своем телефоне можешь найти похожий.

Comment: Все же, стоило прочитать ссылку, чтобы понять, что таймер - это не просто отсчитывалка часов. Это прежде всего, какое-то действие по окончанию установленного срока. Отсчитывалка времени - это просто часы. Не более. Таймер в телефоне - он пищит по окончании отсчета, а не просто время считает. Так вот, все очень сильно зависит от того, нужно ли что-то делать по окончании отсчета или просто показать время. Ибо для последнего - можно просто использовать часы. Они не останавливаются в системе при ожидании ввода. А платформа тут при том, что у разных платформ - своя реализация таймеров и потоков

Comment: Не понимаю при чем тут "делает таймер что или нет" - в вопросе это не имеет значения, нужно только, чтобы отображалось время!!!! Еще раз: нужно, чтобы отображалось время, которое отсчитывает таймер - делает он что-то и что делает - это никакого отношения к вопросу не имеет.

Comment: Самое простое будет, если обработчик таймера раз в 1 секунду будет обновлять строковую переменную. содержащую время и пинать окно от ncurses (каким-нибудь update(), чтобы оно перерисовало себя (вернее, ту изменившуюся по таймеру строку). Как бы Вы сделали это, если бы таймер не мог сделать "что-то", а просто "считал время"?

Comment: Вот только проблема в том, что основная прога в это время ожидает ввод. Получается, что пока не будет введен символ с клавиатуры - ничего вычисляться не будет. Я поэтому и писал о "паралельности".